# Pandas: fastest way to check if words in Series A endswith one word of Series B

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I want to check if the words in a Series named `strings` ends with one words of a Series `ending_strings`.

```
strings = Series(['om', 'foo_nom', 'nom', 'bar_foo', 'foo','blah'])
ending_strings = Series(['nom', 'foo'])
expected_results = Series([False, True, True, True, True, False])
```

I've come up with the following code, but is there a faster, or more pandas style way to do this?

```
from pandas import Series

def ew(v):
    return strings.str.endswith(v) 
result = ending_strings.apply(ew).apply(sum).astype(bool)
result.equals(expected_results)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass `endswith` a tuple here (so you might as well use that instead of a Series):

```
>>> strings = Series(['om', 'foo_nom', 'nom', 'bar_foo', 'foo','blah'])
>>> ending_strings = ("nom", "foo")
>>> strings.str.endswith(ending_strings)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```