# Filtering Pandas Dataframe by the ending of the string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, filter

I have a data frame called df and in one column 'Properties' I have listed properties of some product. These properties are a single sentence. Some of them have the same ending i.e. stock.

I was trying to do something like:

```
df.loc[df['Properties'][-6:] == 'stock']
```

to filter this values but it was not working.

I'd like to implement functionality where I can filter data frame by its last 5 characters.

Do you have any ideas how to do this task?

Comment: U can use ``endswith`` to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668977/pandas-fastest-way-to-check-if-words-in-series-a-endswith-one-word-of-series-b/25669287

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df[df['Properties'].str.endswith('stock')]
```

If you want to try what you were trying, this would work:

```
df = df[df['Properties'].str[-5:]=='stock']
```